# How can I maintain focus on a project?

Tags: professionalism, hours

As I get older I find it harder to maintain focus on a project. I am self employed and this is very important that I can focus on the project at hand and not get side tracked on less important projects.
Are there any good reference materials on maintaining a productive work day when self employed. Like I said at the start, this used to be easier when I was younger, but seems harder to do as I get older. I am not saying the two are related and may be the fact that I have a lot more information coming in then I used to. I have started only reading my email once a day now, this has saved time but not made me any better at keeping focus

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about personal productivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I did face such problem, this might be helpful, try these steps:

1. List out all the task for a week on a paper and add one of these priority tags-(low, medium, high) to each task.
2. when a week is completed you will have the list of all tasks on the priority basis, then you need to separate the task with low and medium priority and jot them in a separate paper and categorize them according to easy, medium, hard level for the task.
3. All the easy & medium are the tasks which need be to delegated to other person, except for some tasks that you alone can complete them.

Delegation has made me really focus on the project.